# Where are the watchdog logs located or how do I view the errors created?

Tags: 6

How do I view the watchdog logs that are created? Is there an interface to view them with, or are the logs stored somewhere on the filesystem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 put the viewable version of watchdog logs at `/admin/reports/dblog`. The core database logging module needs to be enabled, and users who want to view them need the `access site reports` permission. The actual database table is `watchdog`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it, although for some reason my reports were under 'Recent log entries'.

Comment: Yeah, "Recent log entries" is the menu title for the path /admin/reports/dblog.  You can see all of this implemented in modules/dblog/dblog.module in dblog_menu().

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Drush `watchdog-show` e.g.:

```
drush watchdog-show --tail
```

More info: http://drushcommands.com/drush-5x/watchdog/watchdog-show

Comment: The  command worked for me but without the `--tail` option.